# Set 5 textViews in HorizontalLayout to fill it programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I have 5 TextViews created programmatically inside of HorizontalLayout
Can't manage them to fill Layout each with 20% of space.
Usually it can be made by setting width to "MATCH_PARENT", in my case it somehow just adding bunch of space
Screenshots:
[How's that looks without setting width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ9i2.png)
[And if I set width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7VWL.png)
"Name" on screenshots is a part of another layout

Code where I set width

```
val texts = listOf(mealWeightText, mealProteinText, mealFatText, mealCarbonText, mealCaloriesText)
    for (t in texts){
        t.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)}
```

Comment: setWeight to 20